# node.js - correct content security policy for socket.io (web sockets) using helmet

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement content security policies (CSP) in a node server, and am having trouble setting up socket.io. It looks like I am setting up the `connectSrc` incorrectly in the code below. Could someone suggest the correct way to set up helmet so that web socket connections are allowed by the browser? Thanks in advance!

I am using helmet module for generation of CSP; the following is the code that sets up CSP:

```
securitySetup = function(app) {
  var connectSources, helmet, scriptSources, styleSources;
  helmet = require("helmet");
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
  app.use(helmet.noSniff());
  app.use(helmet.crossdomain());
  scriptSources = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "'unsafe-eval'", "ajax.googleapis.com"];
  styleSources = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "ajax.googleapis.com"];
  connectSources = ["'self'"];
  return app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: scriptSources,
    styleSrc: styleSources,
    connectSrc: connectSources,
    reportUri: '/report-violation',
    reportOnly: false,
    setAllHeaders: false,
    safari5: false
  }));
};
```

This works fine for all HTTP/AJAX traffic, but fails for ws:// protocol. I get this error in chrome debugger when socket.io connection is made:

```
Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/websocket/ubexeZHZiAHwAV53WQ7u' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".
```

[image: Chrome Console Error]

Comment: I think your `connectSources` rule is responsible. Does the webserver that serves your application also run on the port 3000? http://content-security-policy.com/ says under *Source List Reference* 'self':  Allows loading resources from the same origin (same scheme, host and port).

Comment: @marco: Yes, the web socket server is the same server as the http server for the web application.  Looks like the same "scheme" part is where the problem is (ws:// vs http://)

Comment: Then I think Patrik Simeks answer should also work for you. Maybe you can give a comment on that or accept it as the correct anwer if it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the address with protocol specified solved the problem for me.

```
connectSources = ["'self'", "ws://localhost:3000"]
```

Comment: Yes, we could do this, but that kind of defeats the purpose of "self" keyword, no? If we need to add the exact server name, port etc, then why do we need this self business?

Answer (score 27):

A close reading of the [Content Security Policy spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/) explains why `'self'` doesn't work:

`'self'` matches requests with the same host, port, *and scheme*. Since your original page loaded with the scheme `http://` or `https://`, `'self'` won't match connections using `ws://`.

This makes `'self'` rather useless for websocket connections. Unless I'm missing something, I think this is a bug in the spec.

Comment: Would be great if this could be remedied somehow, particularly a nuisance for SPA's that get deployed to internal networks (where domain may not always be known or may change frequently).

Answer (score 12):

Bit late to the party, but thought I'd throw something into the mix on this subject. @Ed4 is quite right, `'self'` will indeed only match the same host, port and scheme. A way around it is to include it in one or more forms:

`connect-src: wss:` - to allow a connection to the whole `wss` scheme - basically **any** web socket (probably not ideal)

`connect-src: wss://yoursite.domain.com`  - to restrict it to a specific endpoint. This is most ideal, but might be restrictive if your subdomain changes between deployments (as ours do)

`connect-src: wss://*.domain.com` - can use wildcards in there to tighten security up a bit. This is what we do

**TL;DR** - use wildcards to make things more specific without just opening yourself up to any web sockets out there/

Refer to this passage from Google devs:

> The source list in each directive is flexible. You can specify sources by scheme (data:, https:), or ranging in specificity from hostname-only (example.com, which matches any origin on that host: any scheme, any port) to a fully qualified URI (https://example.com:443, which matches only HTTPS, only example.com, and only port 443). Wildcards are accepted, but only as a scheme, a port, or in the leftmost position of the hostname: *://*.example.com:* would match all subdomains of example.com (but not example.com itself), using any scheme, on any port.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

Comment: Seems like this is not an issue in Chrome anymore ('self' works as expected) but in Safari I had to do `connect-src: wss://*.domain.com` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to automatically add the current host and port in express (es6 syntax):

```
import csp from 'helmet-csp';

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let wsSrc = (req.protocol === 'http' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://') + req.get('host');

  csp({
    connectSrc: ['\'self\'', wsSrc],
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ws: or wss: as keyword for websocket, here is my code use

```
app.use(helmet.csp({
  'default-src': ["'self'"],
  'connect-src': [
    "'self'" , "blob:",
    'wss:',
    'websocket.domain',
  ],
  'font-src': ["'self'",'s3.amazonaws.com',"maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com"],
  'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:'],
  'style-src': ["'self'","maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com",'s3.amazonaws.com',"'unsafe-inline'"],
  'script-src': ["'self'","'unsafe-inline'","'unsafe-eval'",'blob:'],
  reportOnly: false,
  setAllHeaders: false,
  safari5: false
}))
```

with wss://websocket.domain is domain for websocket so if you can use it for localhost